# Is there a way to ignore the Thread Sleep for a certain function?

Tags: c#

So I am currently developing a C# Forms App, and in that Forms App I have a Backgroundworker that loops through a list with DataGridViewRow's, and creates a Thread for each Row. In that Thread, I sleep the program for as long as the user inputs, but I would like to update a string in that Thread while the Thread is sleeping, so basically prevent one function from sleeping inside the Thread itself. Is that possible?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: If the thread is asleep, it's asleep. The thread would have to be awake to call the function. You can't have it both ways - either the thread is running and can do things, or it's sleeping and it can't. Code that isn't in that thread can still run, though. Sounds like you're trying to solve an XY problem, though. What specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks! That's what I thought. Yeah so I basically my program as I said iterates through a list of DataGridViewRow's, and creates a Thread for each Row to do stuff, in that Row they have the decision to delay their action per row by x seconds(Thread.Sleep), but while the Thread is asleep I would like to inform them via a string or a label how much time is left until the next action takes place.

Comment: It sounds like the thread that's about to sleep could just launch a new thread that displays a countdown message and then go to sleep.

Comment: How and where would you track that time for each thread separately?

Comment: @KenWhite Inside my for loop I create the Thread for each Row, and inside the Thread I get the sleep time from a TextBox where the user can input their prefered sleep time, so basically I would just have to count down that value inside the thread.

Comment: Yes, you have that value in the thread, but the thread is asleep. You can't *count down that value in the thread*, because the thread is sleeping. So again, how and where would you track that time for each thread separately? You can't do it in the thread itself if you've called `Thread.Sleep` on that thread.

Comment: You should not be sleeping threads in the first place. Threads are expensive! If it is a worker thread and you don't need it, put it back in the pool and when you need to do more work in the future, grab it back out of the pool again. If it is a UI thread, never sleep it; use Task.Delay.

Comment: This architecture of "one thread per something" is a bad, bad pattern in C#.  If your work is CPU bound then there should be one thread per core, not one thread per work item. If your work is not CPU bound then there should be one thread that manages the latency by using `await`.  You do not want one thread per work item, any more than you want one mail carrier per letter delivered! You should treat threads as though they cost a hundred thousand dollars apiece; you only make a new one when you absolutely have to.

Comment: @SmooK are you making a scheduler-alike application? If you are then you don't need any sleeping threads. You just need a [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.) that will raise an event when the next entry should be processed. Start the worker thread inside the event handler, and then schedule the next timer event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of calling a task that says "Hello", then sleeps for 5 seconds, then says "Goodbye". But while it's sleeping, it starts another task that does a simple countdown.

Maybe this will be helpful to you:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var sleepTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

    var sleepyTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm going to sleep");

        // Before sleeping, launch a countdown timer
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Countdown(sleepTime);
        });

        // Now go to sleep
        Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);

        Console.WriteLine("I'm back!");
    });

    sleepyTask.Wait();

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}

private static void Countdown(TimeSpan time)
{
    var seconds = time.TotalSeconds;

    // Write something once per second for 'seconds' seconds
    while (seconds > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(seconds--);
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
}
```